# PHP - Can I build a dynamic Mongo query using a form?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm a novice-intermediate PHP developer and am starting to work with MongoDB.  I would like to create a **Mongo** query class that builds a query based on the arguments passed into the method.  I hope this is possible and I am just missing some fundamental PHP technique.

I started with a static find function:

```
$dateRange = $this->collection->find(array(

        'timeStamp' => array(
            '$gt' => $startTime,
            '$lt' => $endTime
        ),
        'userAgent' => array(
            '$ne' => 'ELB-HealthChecker/1.0'
        )

));
```

I would like to be able to pass a time range, userAgent, urgency level, etc. into the method and then build the query based on whether those arguments exist. I tried something like this:

```
if($startTime && $endTime){
$filter = "

     'timeStamp' => array(
                '$gt' => $start,
                '$lt' => $end
            )";
}

if($userAgent){
$filter .= ",
        'userAgent' => array(
            '$ne' => 'ELB-HealthChecker/1.0'
        )";

$dateRange = $this->collection->find(array($filter);
```

Didn't work. So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use a string, where you should just use an array.

```php
$qry = array();

if(isset($startTime) && isset($endTime)) {
    // Add the timestamp array
    $qry['timestamp'] = array('$gt' => $startTime, '$lt' => $endTime);
}

if(isset($userAgent)) {
    // add the userAgent
    $qry['userAgent'] = array('$ne' => 'ELB-HealthChecker/1.0');
}

$dateRange = $this->collection->find($qry);
```

Comment: Wow, rough morning.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `if(isset($startTime) && isset($endTime))`? It also seems that you might need a couple of `else` statements in there too.